# Powershell GUI: WPF assign static resource to datagrid column based on bound value

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding, datagrid

I am fairly new to WPF but decent in Powershell. I got stuck designing a GUI for a Powershell script and the customer wants a graphic for one of the columns instead of text.

So, to start off, the requirements are:

- Has to be Powershell 5.1
- Has to be all in one script file
- Data should be sortable and able to be grouped (not shown in test code below)

The images I was given were SVG so I converted those to XAML <DrawingImage> static resources and put those in the <Windows.Resources> section. What I am stuck with now is updating the <Image> source in the custom datagrid column to the correct static resource according to the cell's bound value.

Here is some very basic sample code with one image:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# test form
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Name="GUI">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DrawingImage x:Key="Type1">
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V47.5 H47.5 V0 H0 Z">
                    <DrawingGroup Opacity="1" Transform="1.25,0,0,-1.25,0,47.5">
                        <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="M0,38L38,38 38,0 0,0 0,38z" />
                        </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF66757F" Geometry="F1 M47.5,47.5z M0,0z M30,16.271L30,18.234C31,19.264 32.914,21.124 33.391,23.507 33.532,23.428 33.445,23.377 33.604,23.377 34.361,23.377 34.859,24.361 34.859,25.575 34.859,26.769 34.203,27.736 33.461,27.766 33.604,28.281 33.673,28.972 33.673,29.857 33.673,32.813 31.124,36.362 25.42,36.362 20.352,36.362 17.176,32.813 17.176,29.857 17.176,28.999 17.227,28.295 17.318,27.75 16.621,27.645 16.071,26.717 16.071,25.575 16.071,24.361 16.686,23.377 17.444,23.377 17.602,23.377 17.375,23.428 17.516,23.507 17.993,21.124 20,19.264 21,18.234L21,16.387C17,15.895,14,13.759,14,11.623L14,10.812C14,10,14.823,10,15.634,10L34.364,10C35.177,10,36,10,36,10.812L36,11.623C36,13.623,33,15.619,30,16.271" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF292F33" Geometry="F1 M47.5,47.5z M0,0z M18,8.271L18,10.234C19,11.264 20.914,13.124 21.391,15.507 21.532,15.428 21.445,15.377 21.604,15.377 22.361,15.377 22.859,16.361 22.859,17.575 22.859,18.769 22.203,19.736 21.461,19.766 21.604,20.281 21.673,20.972 21.673,21.857 21.673,24.813 19.124,28.362 13.42,28.362 8.351,28.362 5.176,24.813 5.176,21.857 5.176,20.999 5.227,20.295 5.318,19.75 4.621,19.645 4.071,18.717 4.071,17.575 4.071,16.361 4.686,15.377 5.444,15.377 5.602,15.377 5.375,15.428 5.516,15.507 5.993,13.124 8,11.264 9,10.234L9,8.387C5,7.895,2,5.759,2,3.623L2,2.812C2,2,2.823,2,3.634,2L22.364,2C23.177,2,24,2,24,2.812L24,3.623C24,5.623,21,7.619,18,8.271" />
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Window.Resources>

     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Testing" Foreground="Indigo" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5"  />
        <DataGrid Name="dgDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Type}" Height="12" Stretch="Uniform" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding Col1}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
 </Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

$GUI.Add_Loaded({
    # test data returned from function
    $testData = 1..5 | % { 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Type = "Type$_"
            Col1 = "someData"
            Col2 = "longer test data"
        }
    }

    # @() Prevent error with 1 row data returned
    $dgDataGrid.ItemsSource = @($testData)
})

[void]$GUI.ShowDialog()
```

I'd like to avoid converting the vector images to Bitmap or using a converter, which I don't understand how to implement in Powershell, as the images will be used in other areas of the GUI at different scaling.

I've tried setting the Key value of the drawing image to match the cooresponding returned value but that is not working. The drawing image shows up fine if I use <Image Source="{StaticResource Type1}">. I also tried setting Type to "{StaticResource $*}" so the value shows up as $* but that didn't work either.

I'd like to avoid looping through the datagrid updating the column cell source value of the image tag as that would just add additional time before displaying the results. Ideally, the returned property $testData.Type would determine the static resource used.

Welcome any advice you can give. FYI, I've seen a few complicated C# and .NET suggestions however I don't understand either and ask any advice be given in Powershell if possible, or at least explain the terms and logic.